# Git rebase diverged

Tags: git

I want to rebase my branch (branch) on master (main). commit m1 means I have added a comment with the string m1 to the file. m2, b1 and so on are the same. What I do is:

```
git checkout branch
gitk --all
```

[image]

```
git rebase main
```

*First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: b1
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M   HelloWorld.java
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging HelloWorld.java
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in HelloWorld.java
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 b1
hint: Use 'git am --show-current-patch' to see the failed patch
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".*

```
#I fix the conflicts and add the file.
git rebase --continue
```

*Applying: b1
Applying: b2
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M   HelloWorld.java
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging HelloWorld.java
Applying: b3
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M   HelloWorld.java
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging HelloWorld.java
Applying: b4
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M   HelloWorld.java
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging HelloWorld.java
Applying: b5*

```
git status
```

*On branch branch
Your branch and 'origin/branch' have diverged,
and have 7 and 5 different commits each, respectively.
(use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
nothing to commit, working tree clean*

```
gitk --all
```

[image]

I would like to know why it gets diverged and why the rebase do not work properly, what is causing it, and how can I fix it? am I doing the rebase wrong? When trying to figure out how to fix this issue, only thing I can find is how to go back to the first state (pic 1) with:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/<branchname>
```

Comment: i think it works properly, your local <branch> now have commit from <main> branch. and your remote <branch> still an older version of it. what you expect ?

Comment: Why it gets diverged: because when rebasing master into branch, GIT first rewind branch to first common commit ancestor. In your case it seems that there are not any. So GIT takes commit from master (m1), which makes a new "commit base" for your branch (that's why rebase) and then apply all your branch commits one after the other on top of them. When doing so, new commits are created, so the commit hashes of branch on local are different from the ones on origin. That is why you get a "they have diverged" message.

Comment: just push your branch, <git push origin +branch> to make your local and remote align

Comment: what confuses me is the message "7 and 5 different commits each". I have not tried to push yet since git is recommending "git pull", but this suggestion can not be correct? I did not see push as an option.

Comment: your local "branch" have 7 commit added 2 by master. your remote "branch" is older version only have 5.

Comment: i read again your question, i think you wrong executing, if you want to rebase your master, Checkout to master, and git rebase <feature-branch>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rebase worked as intended. And if you hadn't pushed the branch before rebasing `git status` would be perfectly happy. The misunderstanding has more to do with remotes.

What happens when you push a normal branch. You have some new commits that have the remote branch in their history. When you push the commits get uploaded and the remote branch gets fast forwarded to where your local branch is.

The fast forward is important, because you can not solve merge conflicts on the remote. But if you rebase for example the remote branch will no longer be in the history of your branch. So you can not push normally and this is what `git status` is warning you about.

In your case you know why it diverged and have checked that nobody else has commits made to branch. you can solve this by `git push --force-with-lease`

Answer (score 1):

I think your doing it wrong, you checkout to `branch` and rebase master, which mean you applying change to your `branch`

If you want to apply change feature branch to master :

```
git checkout master
git rebase <feature-branch>
```

ps : imho, would be nice to naming git branch not `branch`, but something like `feature-x` or any, to not confuse.

Comment: This is me using rebase for the first time. From my understanding I should first checkout the branch and then rebase it to master, push branch. When that is done I should checkout master and rebase it with origin/branch. Isnt that correct?

Comment: is your goal is update master branch or feature branch?

Comment: rebase is kind similar like merge. but instead create another dummy commit like merge, rebase is applying commit to your branch without create dummy commit (a 
bit oversimplify).

Comment: In this case, master branch, but at the same time if I have to update feature branch sometime in the future I learn how to do it both ways. I also thought this may be the "better" way, to not mess up the master branch in some way, first see if everything is working as expected before I rebase and push it on master.

Comment: you already update your branch feature corectly, your commit on master already on feature branch, that is what rebase is. but if you want to update master branch on the first thing, just git checkout master and git rebase feature.

Comment: by the way, in my experience, better you use git merge to applying works to master since master will be use by other dev, rebase will mess up history of master branch. use git rebase only on your local feature branch when u really know what happen to that branch.